# Play wav file on Raspberry using Java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, wav, clip

How can I reproduce a .wav file using Java on Raspberry (OS: Raspbian)?
I tried this and it worked, but not anymore: now the program crashes when it tries to play the file (and I don't know why):

```
try{
   File adv = new File(pathRasp+"Suoni/avviso20.wav");
   Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
   clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(adv));
   clip.start();
}catch(IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex){
   System.out.println("ERROR" + ex);
}
```

Anyone know any other ways to reproduce .wav files?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: yes, some exceptions but anyway my program doesn't go ahead, it crashes.

Comment: So show us the messages. Maybe we can help you at this point

Comment: EXCEPTIONS:
org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.create Stream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.Open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.Open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:402)
org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.Open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:453)
Thermaskin(MyProgram).advEnd(Thermaskin.java:1432)
Thermaskin.accesso$4100(Thermaskin.java:71)

Comment: it also says "invalid format" but I don't understand ... Why did it work before and now it doesn't?

Comment: What changes you have done. Maybe a corrupted wav file? You should also printout the stacktrace to see what is happening

Comment: Ehm, let me explain. I'm programming on a Windows PC, and after doing whatever I have to do, I copy it and move it to a raspberry with a pendrive. The .wav file works perfectly on windows, but not on the raspberry (I don't even have a way to debug)

Comment: What do you mean with "reproduce"?

Comment: Wav files can contain audio in several different audio coding formats. You may have one that Windows can deal with but Pulse Audio doesn't handle.

Comment: thanks everyone for replying, I solved the problem. The problem was that I had installed version 8.0 of the jdk instead of version 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this blog post which may or may not help:

https://nealvs.wordpress.com/2017/08/11/java-sound-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-openjdk/

> I was pretty bummed when my sound stopped playing on my Raspberry Pi
> when I switched to OpenJDK 8 after originally using Oracle JDK 8.
>
> Editing the sound.properties for the OpenJDK solved my problem.
>
> sudo vim /etc/java-8-openjdk/sound.properties
>
> Comment out the icedtea classpath configs:
>
> #javax.sound.sampled.Clip=org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixerProvider
> #javax.sound.sampled.Port=org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixerProvider
> #javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine=org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixerProvider
> #javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine=org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixerProvider
>
> Remove the comments from the sun classpath configs:
>
> javax.sound.sampled.Clip=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
> javax.sound.sampled.Port=com.sun.media.sound.PortMixerProvider
> javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
> javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
>
> Problem solved.

In other words, you might have a different JDK between your Windows and Raspi, and they need different configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was that I had installed version 8.0 of the jdk instead of version 11. Thank you again!